# How to debug an external usercontrol in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, catel

I'm using the Catel Focus usercontrol as shown below in my program. When the mouse enters the second TextBox, focus changes to the first. I'd like to use the debugger to step through the Catel code so I can understand its behavior. If I could set a breakpoint in my program that's reached when Focus is activated, then I could single step from there. But the code in my program isn't involved so there's nothing to breakpoint. How can I do this?

```
<TextBox Text="Test force trigger" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <catel:Focus FocusMoment="Event" Source="{Binding ElementName=mouseEnter}" EventName="MouseEnter" FocusDelay="0" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
<TextBox Name="mouseEnter" Text="Mouse Enter"/>
```

Comment: Do you have the code of the dll?

Comment: You could download the code from [GitHub](https://github.com/Catel/Catel) and replace the NuGet packages with references to the local assemblies or projects. This will let you use breakpoints in the downloaded code as usual.

Comment: Thanks. I've cloned, built and referenced the Catel DLLs. What I hadn't realized is that I can open the Catel source files in VS (File > Open > File) and set breakpoints there. So I guess I'm OK. Is there some way access the DLL file sources via Solution Explorer in my program?

Comment: You could refer to document [Debug a DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-dll-projects?view=vs-2019#vxtskdebuggingdllprojectswaystodebugthedll)
and [Set function breakpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Set_a_breakpoint_in_a_source_file), and they may be give you some help